# Drop Down IE 8 and Below Not Working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I just finished redesigning my site to include drop down menus, but I learned today that IE 8 and below don't display them any where near correctly. It displays fine to my knowledge on every other browser. 
I don't know where I've gone wrong, but I've been debugging and haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a jsfiddle with my html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/scTqy/

Here is the link to the live site: http://www.hearditfrom.com

---

(This is in the js fiddle)

Here is my html/php:

```
        <nav id="hb2_nav">
       <ul>
    <li><a class="hb2_nav" href="category.php">Categories <span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="drop-shadow">
    <span class="category_column">
    <li><a href="category.php?category=1">U.S.</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=2">World</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=3">Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=4">Economy</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=5">Entertainment</a></li>
    </span>
    <span class="category_column">
    <li><a href="category.php?category=6">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=7">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=8">Odd News</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=9">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=10">Science</a></li>
    </span>
    <span class="category_column_last">
    <li><a href="category.php?category=11">Special Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=12">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.php?category=13">Technology</a></li>
    </span>

    </ul></li>
    <li><a class="hb2_nav" href="">Add </a></li>
    <li><a class="hb2_nav" href="">Edit </a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here is my css:

```
   #hb2_nav
   {
     font-size:18px;
     line-height: 55px;
     float:right;
     height:55px;
     margin:0px;
     margin-top:0px;
     padding:0px;
     display:inline;
    }

        #hb2_nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        color: #333;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
    #hb2_nav ul li:hover {
        background: none;
    }
    #hb2_nav ul li:hover a {
        text-decoration:none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right:10px;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        display: block; /*padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;*/
    }

    #hb2_nav ul ul {
        background: #ffffff; /*#FFF8F0;*/ 
        border-radius: 0px; 
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 100%;
        width:100%;
        min-width:250px;
        max-width: 400px;
        z-index:10000;
        border: 2px solid #999;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul ul:before {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        width:0;
        border:15px solid #999;
        border-color:transparent transparent #999 transparent;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:100%;
        left:20px;
        margin-left:-10px;
    }



    #hb2_nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        text-align:left;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }

    #hb2_nav ul ul li a {
        color: #333;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    #hb2_nav ul ul li:hover a {
        background: #e8e8e8;
    }
```

Comment: Just saying... you go into php just to echo out html? Gonna have to say NOOOOOOOO to that... just sayin.

Comment: I just changed the nav tag to a div tag, and that makes it work on IE 8, but on IE 7, the drop down is still being displayed oddly.

I also took out some of the stuff I needed the php for, sorry about that

Comment: See this post for adding html5 tags to older browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996413/html5-for-ie8-or-less

Comment: Any idea on why it may not be working on IE 7 with just a div tag?

Comment: Aside from ie7 being a flaming POS, It MIGHT be possible it doesn't like li nested within span tags unless those span tags are being set to display block. However, i seriously doubt that is to blame for the behavior I get when I check your site. Perhaps the problem is how you're defining the positions of the menus in relation to their parents. Subtle side note, you get some whacky behavior when you hover over the bottom items in the category menu. it pushes the content right off the screen

Comment: It pushes it off above IE 7?

Comment: no, I checked in IE7. 8 and 9 are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You used `<nav>` which is a HTML5 element, which is NOT supported by IE8 and below.

Use only HTML4.01 tags & JavaScript for better support of older browsers.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work on IE 7 and below with a div tag instead of a nav tag

Comment: With only CSS and HTML , you do not have the drop down logic. Use JavaScript.