# CSS troubleshooting for Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am making a website that unfortunately needs to be compatible with IE 8. I have successfully implemented some changes, as I understand that at least HTML5 is not working.

But I am struggling with finding the right thing to do in this case.

This JSFiddle gives a good simplified representation of my problem code. The wanted output works in my Chrome version. http://jsfiddle.net/kjetilnordin/g6FGv/

There is a single row, and three cells inside a table. The three cells split the space equally in between themselves, and do not take their content size into consideration. Now, I have toggleboxes that can turn the cells invisible or visible back again. I want the remaining cells to take up all the space of their parent, split in 1, 2, or 3 visible cells.

In IE 8 the cells remain at their 1/3 size, and only move to the left, when a cell further left is turned invisible.

I expected that one of the CSS properties was not supported, but I've checked them all, and they should work.

So what is it that is not playing along here? A solution would be nice, but a nudge in the right direction would be just as appreciated.

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="foo">
            foo
        </td>
        <td class="bar">
            bar
        </td>
        <td class="foobar">
            foobar
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="togglebox" value="foo">toggle off foo</input></br>
<input type="checkbox" class="togglebox" value="bar">toggle off bar</input></br>
<input type="checkbox" class="togglebox" value="foobar">toggle off foobar</input></br>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("."+this.value).toggle(false);
    } else {
         $("."+this.value).toggle(true);
    }
});
```

css:

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you can partial enable html5 in IE8 using some js-libraries. Look here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996413/html5-for-ie8-or-less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as crazy as it sounds, *IE8 is technically right*. Chrome is non-standard here in favour of keeping to expected behaviour.

`table-layout:fixed` means to fix the table layout regardless of content, including changes to said content. This allows for faster rendering of tables.

Unfortunately this means there's no easy way to ensure equal-width columns while having the number of columns be variable by the toggles.

You will need to remove `table-layout:fixed` and have JavaScript calculate the appropriate `width` percentage on load, and whenever the number of columns changes.

Comment: That is too bad, but I am going to try a little tweak before I give up. In my actually project code, the table I have described is in fact inside anoter table's td. I have a hope that I can keep the table-layout: fixed on the parent table, but remove it from the child table, and see what happens. Thank you for the input though, it was most educational :). I'll experiment a little with it before accepting it as an answer, as I always do :)